# Xcode can't find Info.plist or Prefix.pch when making a Release build

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have a project that shares some files between a Mac application and an iPad app.  Because of this, I moved the Info.plist and Prefix.pch files for each one into sub folders for Mac and iPad, respectively.  I can build the iPad app in Debug configuration without issue, for the simulator and for a device.  I get the following messages in the build results:

> Process iPad/Fogozine-Info.plist
>
> Precompile iPad/Fogozine_Prefix.pch

with a big green check mark next to both.  Everything is fine.

When I build for Release, though, I get the following:

> Process Fogozine-Info.plist
>
> The file "Fogozine-Info.plist" couldn't be opened because there is no such file.
>
> Precompile Fogozine_Prefix.pch
>
> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

with big red exclamation marks next to them.  Is there some build setting I'm missing that's specific to the release build?  I can see there's an Info.plist entry in the Build settings, but the end result is the same regardless of if I leave it empty, set it to iPad, or set it to iPad/Fogozine-Info.plist, for all build configurations.  I don't see anything related to the Prefix.pch file.  This seems like a bug in Xcode.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it.  I was looking in the Project's build settings, but I needed to look in the Target's build settings.  The two settings I needed to modify were `Info.plist File` and `Prefix Header`.  When I modified them initially, I must have only modified them for the Debug Build Configuration.